How to draw an arc with images and inner content in Compose?
I have been tried to do the this in Compose:

But when I started to try to add the images, I really don´t know how to keep going, all images are drawables
This is what I have tried:
@Composable
fun ZMTBottomSelector(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .shadow(8.dp, clip = true, shape = ZMTArcShape())
            .background(color = Color.White),
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = { },
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                .padding(top = 120.dp),
        ) {
            Text(text = "Continuar")
        }
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        }
    }
    /*Canvas(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(top = 16.dp),
    ) {
        val newSize = Size(width = size.width * 2, height = size.width * 2)
        drawArc(
            color = Color.White,
            startAngle = 0f,
            sweepAngle = 360f,
            useCenter = false,
            size = newSize,
            topLeft = Offset(-(size.width / 2), 0f),
        )
    }*/
}

ZMTArchShape code:
class ZMTArcShape : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density,
    ): Outline {
        val newSize = Size(size.width * 2, size.width * 2)
        val path = Path().apply {
            val rect = Rect(offset = Offset(-(size.width / 2), 0f), size = newSize)
            addArc(
                oval = rect,
                startAngleDegrees = 0f,
                sweepAngleDegrees = 360f,
            )
        }
        return Outline.Generic(path)
    }
}

And this is what it looks like:


I have given a solution for a different question it will be helpful for you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/78394050/8968956

My main issue is to draw the images across de arc, Do you know any idea to do that?
